# Best way include a layout with many child layouts with a navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My problem in short: How to include a complicated layout into a navigation drawer.

I have a my main activity with viewpager,fragment and here is the code of my mainactivity initially

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="GGG" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/text_fragment"
    android:name="com.sample.fragment.HomeButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to introduce navigation drawer to this. I figured two ways of doing it

1.Including the above layout in the framelayout(content_frame) of the navigation drawer (I tried but didnt work for me)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2.Creating a new fragment and include the above layout to this, now our mainactivity contains a new fragment+navigation drawer.

please tell me how to do this.

Comment: *I tried but didnt work for me* - what exactly happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried in the 1st method dat i mentioned above but it throws an error in the view(layout). I guess the problem should be with the nested layouts.